# Auto fill sequential numbers column A according to the row count of column B

Tags: excel, vba, userform, fill

I'm trying to fill item numbers automatically when I press a button. Here is my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BİLGİLER")

lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Formula = "=row()"
```

It fills in column A but it begins with 2 instead of 1. So numbers are ordered like 2, 3, 4 etc.

I could not find why it does like that... What did I go wrong? What should I do?

Comment: corrected code ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow &"").Formula = "=row()"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the numbering from "1" in row 1, just change A2 to A1:-

```
ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Formula = "=row()"
```

But if you mean the numbering should start with a "1" in A2, then you need to subtract 1:-

```
ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Formula = "=row()-1"
```

Comment: A1 has its own data so I can not start from A1 and my friend, the second code piece of yours worked like a charm. I was so struck with consternation that I could not think of it. :) Thanks a lot anyway.